# header fixed issue in html to pdf using puppeteer in nestjs

Tags: html, css, puppeteer, pdf-generation, ejs

I am generating a report in puppeteer using nestjs in which i have header and below that tables which are dynamic. My header is fixed and when my number of table increases it shifts to next page but on second page my table is going behind the table. for example if my loop is generating 5 tables then 4 is on first page but 5th table which goes to 2nd page of PDF is printed under the top header of second page. here is my html code:

```
<div style="padding: 10px;">
    <% if (setting?.showLogo == true) { %>
        <div class="header" id="header" style="padding: 0px 10px;">
            <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="<%= mylogo %>" style="max-width: 100%;" alt="Laboratory Header">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <% } %>

    <div style="margin-top:180px"></div>
    

    <div style="height: 0.5px; background-color: #000; width: 100%;"></div>

    <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 9px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table class="mynewpadding" style=" text-align: left;">
                        <tbody>                        
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="float: left; font-weight: bold; font-size: small;">Patient Name :</td>
                                    <td style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; font-size: small;"><%= invoice.patient.patient_name %></td>
                                </tr>
                                
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
               
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div style="height: 0.5px; background-color: #000; width: 100%;"></div>

    <% for (const report of reports) { %>
        <table style="float: left; width: 60%; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 20px 0px; font-size: small;" >
            <thead>
                <tr>                     
                    <td style="font-size: 18px; font-size: medium; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-top: 17px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">
                        <%= report?.labTemplate?.testName %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                  
                    <% for (const item of report.report_tableHead) { %>
                        <% if (item.active === 1 && item.name !== 'SUBHEADING') { %>
                            <% if (item.name === 'RESULTS' || item.name === 'Results' || item.name === 'results') { %>
                            <% } else { %>
                                <th style="padding: 10px; text-align: left; border: 1px solid #000; background-color: #dddddd; text-transform: capitalize;">
                                    <%= item.name %>
                                </th>
                            <% } %>
                        <% } %>
                    <% } %>
                </tr>
            </thead>                            
            <tbody style="text-align: left;">
                <% for (const item of report.report_tableBody) { %>
                    <% if (Object.values(item).some(value => value !== '' && value !== null)) { %>
                        <tr>
                            <% if (item.test !== '') { %>
                                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left;"><%= item.test %></td>
                            <% } %>
                            <% if (item.type !== '') { %>
                                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left;"><%= item.type %></td>
                            <% } %>                                              
                        </tr>
                    <% } %>
                <% } %>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table style="float: right; width: 40%; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 20px 0px; font-size: small;" >
            <thead>                 
                <tr>
                    <% let hasResultsColumn = false; %>
                    <% for (const item of report.report_tableHead) { %>
                        <% if (item.active === 1 && item.name !== 'SUBHEADING') { %>
                            <% if (item.name === 'RESULTS' || item.name === 'Results' || item.name === 'results') { %>
                                <th class="barcode-header" style="height: 50px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000; text-transform: capitalize; background-color: #dddddd;">
                                    <%= item.name %> 
                                </th>
                            <% } else { %>                              
                            <% } %>
                        <% } %>
                    <% } %>
                    <% if (previousResults) { %>
                        <% hasResultsColumn = true; %>
                        <% let prevResultCount = 0; %>
                        <% for (const prevResult of previousResults) { %>
                            <% if (prevResultCount < 2) { %>
                                <td class="barcode-header" style="height: 50px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #000; text-transform: capitalize; background-color: #dddddd;">
                                    Results
                                </td>
                                <% prevResultCount++; %>
                            <% }  %>
                        <% } %>
                    <% } %>
                </tr>
            </thead>                            
            <tbody style="text-align: left;">
                <% for (const item of report.report_tableBody) { %>
                    <% if (Object.values(item).some(value => value !== '' && value !== null)) { %>
                        <tr>                    
                            <% if (item.result !== '') { %>
                                <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left;"><%= item.result %></td>
                            <% } %>
                            <% if (hasResultsColumn) { %>
                                <% let prevResultCount = 0; %>
                                <% for (const prevResult of previousResults) { %>
                                    <% if (prevResultCount < 2) { %>
                                        <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: left;"><%= prevResult[0].result %></td>
                                        <% prevResultCount++; %>
                                    <% }  %>
                                <% } %>
                            <% } %>
                        </tr>
                    <% } %>
                <% } %>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <% } %>                         
</div>
```

[image: this is how it shows after generating:]